# Spring boot ManagedExecutorService instance

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat

We are creating a new Spring Boot project and a part of it needs multi-threading operation. We are trying to use the ManagedExecutorService, so we declared it as follows:

```
@Resource(name="java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService")  
private ManagedExecutorService mes;
```

And during execution returned the error:

> ```
> Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is 
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
> Invalid bean definition with name 'java:comp/DefaultManagedExecutorService' defined in JNDI environment: JNDI lookup failed; nested exception is 
> javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in 
> environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an 
> application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
> ```

Does this means that Spring Boot does not support/allow us to use the ManagedExecutorService in tomcat?

Comment: Don't... Either use the Spring `DefaultManagedTaskExecutor` which taps into that or just configure a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. Also I doubt there will be one if you use the embedded tomcat, which is what the exception hints at.